# How to change pts for a part of a video file with ffplay?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I can use setpts filter to change pts for an entire video file,  But I don't know how to change pts for a part of video file.

For example :

If the duration is 3 minutes. How to change speed for only the second minute in ffplay?  (not ffmpeg)

Sorry for my English.